# Scrape splits from Yahoo

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape splits from Yahoo for this date 2017-08-01, splits are shown in the uploaded picture,

**splits in 2017-08-01**

[image]

As per the picture uploaded, I should get 'SVU',
Here is my code,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/splits?day=2017-08-01")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
driver.quit()
```

I don't know to continue and how to get the data of first column ('SVU'),
Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/splits?day=2017-08-01")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
Symbol=soup.find("td",{"class" :"data-col0 Ta(start) Pend(15px) Pstart(15px) W(10%)"}).text
company=soup.find("td",{"class" :"data-col1 Ta(start) Pend(10px) W(20%)"}).text
payable_on=soup.find("span",{"data-reactid" :"41"}).text
ex_date=soup.find("span",{"data-reactid" :"43"}).text

optionalable=soup.find("td",{"class" :"data-col4 Ta(end) Pstart(15px) W(10%)"}).text
ratio=soup.find("td",{"class" :"data-col5 Ta(end) Pstart(15px) W(10%)"}).text
announced=soup.find("span",{"data-reactid" :"47"}).text

print("Symbol is {} \n Company is {} \n Payable on {} \n Ex Date {} \n Optionable ? {} \n ratio {} \n announced {}".format(Symbol,company,payable_on,ex_date,optionalable,ratio,announced))


driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
Symbol is SVU 
 Company is Supervalu 
 Payable on 0.00% 
 Ex Date Aug 01 
 Optionable ? Y 
 ratio 1.00 - 7.00 
 announced Aug 01
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will fetch you all the data needed as per your requirement.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/splits?day=2017-08-01")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
driver.quit()

item = soup.select("tr.data-rowSVU")[0]
for data in item.select("td"):
    print(data.text)
```

Results:

```
SVU
Supervalu
Aug 01
Aug 01
Y
1.00 - 7.00
Aug 01
```